# I want to hide a loading spinner when I first open it on the browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

[image]

**That's the problem**

I want to hide loading spinner when I open it on the browser. It's spinning all the time.

When I choose something on the select box or type to search, it works.
it hid the spinner correctly when I did that.
let me know how to fix it thanks

```js
function searchFilter(page_num) {

    page_num = page_num ? page_num : 0;
    var keywords = $('#keywords').val();
    var filterBy = $('#filterBy').val();

    $('#loading').hide()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getData1.php',
        data: 'page=' + page_num + '&keywords=' + keywords + '&filterBy=' + filterBy,
        beforeSend: function() {

            $('.spinner-border').show();

        },
        success: function(html) {
            $('#dataContainer').html(html);
            $('.spinner-border').fadeOut("slow");
        },

    });
}
```

```html
<div id="loading" class="spinner-border" role="status">
```

Im a newbie for AJAX.
I tried to drop `$('#loading').hide()`. I saw it on someone's problem.
but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to show some html code as well. Try to give as much as you can or start a jsfiddle or create css/html/js when adding code to show how it is.

Comment: Move `$('#loading').hide()` to in doc.ready (move out of `searchFilter` -> `$(() => { $('#loading').hide() });`

Comment: thank you for the answer everyone finally i did it thank you to Yogi, i added  <style>
   .spinter {
  display: none;
}
    </style>